# Help with a parabolic partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I have the following PDE: $$A \cdot x^2 \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x^2}(x,y) +(B \cdot x-C)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)-B \cdot f(x,y) =0 $$

And as condition I have: $$ f(x,y)/x \leq 1 \\ f(0,y)=0 \\ f(x,0) = max(0, x-D)$$

with A,B,C and D which are known and positive.

Could anyone help me with this, please? What really confuse me is how to proceed when the conditions are not equalities...